# Display Node Index on PrimeNG Tree Nodes

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

Since `p-tree` from `PrimeNG` does not have way of using `rowIndex`.
How do I display/get the Index of nodes each node using `ng-template`.

Is there any workaroud?

Comment: i think you will get the required information of node from its event using (onNodeExpand)="loadNode($event)"

Comment: I would like to get the node index before no is being clicked by user and expanded.
I would like to display the indexes (1,2,3,...) on each node.

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 1):

Within the `ng-template`, you can call the [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method on your collection and pass the current item as the argument. This will either return the index of the first instance of that item or `-1` if that item isn't found. You can display the result of that call within curly braces in the HTML.

```
<p-tree [value]="items">
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="default">
        <span>{{ items.indexOf(item) }}</span>
    </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```